# Numba and random numbers from poisson distribution

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, random, numba

I found that one of the bottlenecks in my simulations is the generation of random numbers from a poisson distribution. My original code works like this

```
import numpy as np
#Generating some data. In the actual code this comes from the previous
#steps in the simulation. But this gives an example of the type of data
n = 5000000
pop_n = np.array([range(500000)])

pop_n[:] = np.random.poisson(lam=n*pop_n/np.sum(pop_n))
```

Now, I read that numba can increase the speed very simply. I defined the function

```
from numba import jit

@jit()
def poisson(n, pop_n, np=np):
    return np.random.poisson(lam=n*pop_n/np.sum(pop_n))
```

This one indeed run faster than the original. However, I try to go further :) When I wrote

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def poisson(n, pop_n, np=np):
    return np.random.poisson(lam=n*pop_n/np.sum(pop_n))
```

I got

```
Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Invalid usage of Function(np.random.poisson) with parameters     (array(float64, 1d, C))
Known signatures:
 * (float64,) -> int64
 * () -> int64
 * parameterized
```

Some questions Why is this error happening and how to fix it.

Is there a better optimization?

Comment: Looks like Numba does not yet support returning arrays from any of the np.random functions. You should first set an empty array specifying the type of its items and only after you can add the values. Look here for an example https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1596

Comment: I don't see any practical reason why jitting this function should be any faster. `np.random.poisson` is already implemented in C. Wrapping it in another compiled function will at best get optimized away by the compiler and at worst cause overhead.

Comment: @kazemakase What about the operations on pop_n? The division of the array by it's on sum?

Comment: @DiogoSantos these operations are likely negligible compared to generating random numbers. I `%timeit`ed your `poisson` function with and without `@jit` and did not see any improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numba doesn't support an array as `lam` parameter for `np.random.poisson`, so you have to do the loop yourself:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def poisson(n, pop_n):
    res = np.empty_like(pop_n)
    pop_n_sum = np.sum(pop_n)
    for idx, item in enumerate(range(pop_n.shape[0])):
        res[idx] = np.random.poisson(n*pop_n[idx] / pop_n_sum)
    return res

n = 5000000
pop_n = np.array(list(range(1, 500000)), dtype=float)
poisson(n, pop_n)
```

But according to my timings this is just as fast as using pure NumPy:

```
%timeit poisson(n, pop_n)
# 203 ms ± 1.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit np.random.poisson(lam=n*pop_n/np.sum(pop_n))
# 203 ms ± 3.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

That's because even though Numba supports `np.random.poisson` and functions like `np.sum` these are only supported as convenience not actually to speed up the code (much). It probably can avoid the function call overhead to some extend but given that it would only call the `np.random.poisson` once in pure Python that's not much (and totally negligible compared to creating half a million random numbers).

Numba is blazingly fast if you want to speed up a loop that you **can't do with pure NumPy** but you shouldn't expect that numba (or anything else) can provide major speedups to equivalent NumPy functions. If it was easily possible to make them faster - the NumPy developers would make it faster too. :)

Comment: As an extra for other people trying to speed up random number generation I just found random_intel, and it seems like it runs much faster than base numpy

Comment: @DiogoSantos What `random_intel` do you mean? I can't find any documentation on that function. Do you have a link for that? That could be very useful :)

Comment: that was inded a very vague comment. I'm talking about python-intel. The benchmark for random number generation can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2016/06/15/faster-random-number-generation-in-intel-distribution-for-python)